# d3.js: Color by group based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, radio-button

I'm a newbie using d3.js to create a multi-level filter plot based on user selections. All filters are working except[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yoFCbe?p=preview) the categorical color selection. Colors are defaulting to fluid type (default should be material type) and using the radio button to switch doesn't work. Can anyone help?

https://plnkr.co/edit/yoFCbe?p=preview

```
function filter_color(){
    colored = document.getElementById("color_Filter");
    svg.append("circle")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (colored == 0) {
                return color(d["Material group"]);
            } else {
                return color(d["Fluid type"]);
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for the actual value of the radio box.
Get the `checked`/`unchecked` state and that if statement will run as it should:

```
 colored = document.getElementById("color_Filter")[0].checked; // <= mind here
  if (colored == 0) {
        return color(d["Material group"]);
  } else {
        return color(d["Fluid type"]);
  }
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/gZOIbDgYj6OCs5aM1CV2?p=preview